# Не могу открыть wordpress файл phpstorm

Tags: linux, wordpress, phpstorm

Не могу открыть wordpress файл phpstrormom. Думаю, что это из-за того, что права доступа давал wordpress папке. (без прав были проблемы с установкой плагинов на wp). Скачал чистый wordpress ради эксперимента и его открыло. Значит, все-таки проблема в правах. Так вот. Как мне открыть этот WordPress на phpstorme? (дебажить удобно им).

Нажимаю открыть, но дальше ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

> Думаю, что это из-за того, что права доступа давал wordpress папке

Правильно думаешь, что проблема в правах. Ещё бы формулировать вопросы научиться.

Открыть не "этот WordPress на phpstorme", а "файл по ФТП".
Для этого нужно правильно настроить сервер. Чтобы фтп-юзеру было позволено править файлы. В идеале у файлов, созданных с помощью php, залитым через ПУ хостинга и ftp-юзера должен быть один серверный владелец (напр владелец аккаунта). Как это делается - вопрос по системному администрированию серверов.

Ни к ВП ни к phpstorm-у это не имеет ни малейшего отношения.